# Getting "End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed." error when deserailizing object to binary

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Shared Function BinaryFileToObject(ByVal Filename As String) As Object
    Try
        If File.Exists(Filename) Then
                          Dim bf As New Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter()
            bf.AssemblyFormat = Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterAssemblyStyle.Full
            bf.TypeFormat = Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterTypeStyle.TypesWhenNeeded
            Using fs As FileStream = IO.File.OpenRead(Filename)
                Try
                    Using ms As New MemoryStream()
                        Dim bytes As Byte() = New Byte(fs.Length - 1) {}
                        fs.Read(bytes, 0, CInt(fs.Length))
                        ms.Write(bytes, 0, CInt(fs.Length))
                        ms.Position = 0
                        Dim obj As EmployeeDetails = bf.Deserialize(ms)
                        Return obj
                    End Using

                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox("There was an exception while trying to convert binary file to object. Exception: " & ex.Message & " | Stacktrace: " & ex.StackTrace)
                Finally
                    If fs IsNot Nothing Then
                        fs.Flush()
                        fs.Close()
                    End If
                End Try
            End Using
        Else
            MsgBox("There is no file found with the name '" & Filename & "' to convert to object.")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("There was an exception while trying to convert binary file to object. Exception: " & ex.Message & " | Stacktrace: " & ex.StackTrace)
    End Try
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

I have serialized a lot of data, but not able to deserailize it, can anybody help to get the object back?

Comment: Is this the code to serialize? You should be including your attempted code to deserialize. Please have a look at [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Here I'm deserializing here

Comment: You dont need to "help" the serializer that much - for instance you dont need to manually read the filestream into a memorystream.  If you are "helping" in similar fashion to serialize the error could be there.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Are your serialized types using custom serialization with `ISerializable`?  If so, please include `GetObjectData` and the serialization constructor from those types.